# Alternatives to LibreOffice

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice

What alternatives to LibreOffice (specially LO Writer) does Ubuntu come with. I have seen Abiword there but are there others?

Comment: You would need to be more specific about what you really expect featurewise. Tautologically, LibreOffice Writers featureset is best covered by LibreOffice Writer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<s>KOffice</s> **Calligra Suite**

The KOffice project was replaced by [Calligra Suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calligra_Suite), after some disputes. [Calligra Suite](http://www.calligra-suite.org/) is a fork of the 2010 codebase.

**IBM Lotus Symphony**

uses code from OpenOffice.org and includes enhancements such as new sidebars in its user interface.

Not in the repositories, but I think it is worth mentioning, you may give it a try and see what it brings new to OpenOffice.org besides the interface

Read more: http://www-03.ibm.com/software/lotus/symphony/home.nsf/home

**Other Useful Options**

For calculations one could use gnumeric, octave and Python with numpy. A fairly good lightweight word processor, Abiword is available.

For document creation, Latex and Context are excellent systems, the learning curve is a little steep when it comes to Tex based document creation systems, but when one starts reaping the rewards of the power of these systems one will see it is a small price to pay.

For people just starting with Latex, an Interface like [lyx](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lyx) [image: Install lyx] may be used. There is no substitute for a good Latex editor though, [texmaker](http://packages.ubuntu.com/texmaker) [image: Install texmaker] is a fine one.

Scribus may also be considered, while it is a page layout program and not a word processor there is a story editor that have similar behaviour to a word processor and there are many instance where something like this is better for document creation than a word processor.

For drawing Xfig and Inkscape are quite good.

For database, sqliteman interface to the sqlite database system

Comment: I am actually looking for alternative to the writer and the rest of a complete office suite. Latex is not really a friendly office suite. Is good that you know them but it is not a real alternative.

Comment: I will accept the answer but if you could add more (including Abiword without paying attention that I mentioned it in the question).

Comment: I was not suggesting Latex to be an Office suite alternative, just the word processing, when used with Lyx or a special Latex editor things can get a lot easier for the beginner, There are serious advantages over word processing so I could not help but mention it.

Comment: Lotus Symphony is only available for Linux on 32 bit operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

**Local one:**

- OpenOffice
- AbiWord
- Lotus

**Network:**

- Google
- Zoho

---

If to talk about free, of course, there's Microsoft one services.

Answer (score 3):

Calligra Suite is the actually developed fork of KOffice.

Comment: http://www.calligra.org/ for more information on this suite and it is also available in the latest Beta 6 on Kubuntu: http://www.kubuntu.org/news/calligra-2.3.86

Answer (score 2):

As i know, [IBM Lotus Symphony's release life cycle has ended](http://www.edbrill.com/ebrill/edbrill.nsf/dx/ibm-lotus-symphony-3.0.1-is-now-available). So i don't think it is a good option anymore. By the way it is also a fork, but [fork of OpenOffice](http://www.datamation.com/entdev/article.php/3703501/OpenOffice-vs-Lotus-Symphony.htm).

Answer (score 1):

At the suggestion of @k0pernikus, I've put my comment into an answer:

Now worth an "answer" but if you have a google account, you can use Google Docs. I find myself using it quite often.

Comment: +1, I prefer google docs for all my work over libreoffice.

Comment: For some Google docs might be sufficient, for me it's not. The major pain I'm facing is ODF compatibility and 20+ features 99% of the people I work with expect you to be able to work with (e.g. Record Changes, custom styles, auto generated Table Of Contents, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

There is also [WPS Office](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/wps-office-for-linux-looks-like-microsoft-office-but-isnt), a Chinese Microsoft Office clone.

Note: I haven't tried it out myself yet, but you will find a number of testimonies in the comment section of the link above.