# what text editors are available for ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, programming, text-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu)
>   [Alternatives to LibreOffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96376/alternatives-to-libreoffice)

What Text Editors are available for Ubuntu?

I would like text editors for all usages.

Programming

Writing

Hex editing

Comment: Why is this closed? IDE isn't editor, nor is textprocessing - they only have something with editors in common.

Comment: I know but they closed it and down voted my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something like an alternative for Notepad++ the best option is Gedit or Emacs:

- [Geany](http://www.geany.org/)
- [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)
- [Aptana](http://aptana.com/)
- [Bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/download.html)
- gedit (default in Ubuntu)